# Chart.js only displays font changes upon hover

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**Problem**

I have a Laravel website with multiple charts and a 'nightmode' button. This button turns the page dark and the text light.

The function looks like this:

```
   function darkMode(){
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("day")[0];
    element.classList.toggle("night");

    if(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor == 'black'){
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'white'

    } else {
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black'
    }
}
```

This function works perfectly except for the following issue:
When the button is pressed the new font color only shows when the cursor hovers over the chart.

**Steps taken**

- I have tried to update the chart (as is advised in the chart.js documentation) after the nightmode function finished with *chart.update()*

However I get the error stating:

> chart.update is not a function.

- Selecting a specific chart is not an option since I want to use this function to work on multiple pages with multiple charts.
- Making the entire webpage reload for the changes to take place is not preferred either.

**Goal**

To have the chart text change color when the 'nightmode' button is pressed and for the user to not have to hover over the chart first for the changes to take place.

**Extra info**

- Chart.js version 2.9.3 (installed using brew/npm)
- Tested on both Safari and Chrome

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var barChartData = {
   labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
   datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    backgroundColor: [
     window.chartColors.red,
     window.chartColors.orange,
     window.chartColors.yellow,
     window.chartColors.green,
     window.chartColors.blue,
     window.chartColors.purple,
     window.chartColors.red
    ],
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
    data: [
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor()
    ]
   }, {
    label: 'Dataset 2',
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.grey,
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
    data: [
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor(),
     randomScalingFactor()
    ]
   }]

  };
  window.onload = function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
   window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
     responsive: true,
     title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Multi Axis'
     },
     tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true
     },
     scales: {
      yAxes: [{
       type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
       display: true,
       position: 'left',
       id: 'y-axis-1',
      }, {
       type: 'linear', // only linear but allow scale type registration. This allows extensions to exist solely for log scale for instance
       display: true,
       position: 'right',
       id: 'y-axis-2',
       gridLines: {
        drawOnChartArea: false
       }
      }],
     }
    }
   });
  };

  document.getElementById('changeColor').addEventListener('click', function() {
   Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#ff0000"
   window.myBar.update();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 75%">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
 <button id="changeColor">Change To Red Color</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As stated in my question however, this returns a "update is not a function" error message. Also this will update 1 chart "myBar." I would like to reload all charts on the page, since I have multiple pages with multiple charts all with different names.

Comment: code in snippet is bit different than your code which gives you an error. you have to store the all generated charts in variables somewhere in order to update those charts or you can reload all charts.

Comment: I got rid of the error, that was my bad. But currently I can update the graphs only by writing "window.chartName.update()" for each graph I have. Is there a way to update all graphs on the page without needing to specifically call their names?

Comment: I don't think so. Chart.js uses canvas to render the graph. and for all update in rendered graph it needs all inputs again. hence, you have to store generated chart in variable or you have to reload chart with all data again. you can store all the generated charts in an object arrayif you don't want to manage multiple variable names.

Comment: Alright, at least I can continue now again. Thanks for the help! :)